# Im unable to login to my wordpress

Tags: plugins

This morning i tried login but facing issue stating that – There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

But when i checked my inbox I dint find any mail from wordpress.

And when i checked the error log i found this issue : Call to undefined function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() in /home/de2awyowrkup/public_html/wp-settings.php:70
Stack trace:

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your site has tried to update from 5.4 to 5.5 but failed, and you're left with a mix of the two versions that doesn't work.

- in 5.4, wp-settings line 70 called `wp_unregister_GLOBALS()` which was defined in wp-includes/load.php, loaded from wp-settings line 34
- in 5.5, `wp_unregister_GLOBALS` has been deprecated and a placeholder is defined in wp-includes/deprecated.php, which is loaded further down wp-settings.

So you've probably somehow ended up with 5.4's wp-settings.php but 5.5's wp-includes.

You can fix this by manually completing the WordPress Core upgrade. Back up your site first just in case, then follow the [manual upgrade instructions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update) in the WordPress manual: essentially replace all of the WordPress files with a fresh copy but leaving wp-config.php and wp-content/ alone.